# Roll vector so max value is centered and order of values relative to it stay the same

Tags: r

How can I roll a vector so the max value is in the middle and the order of values relative to it stay the same?

If the length of the vector is even, then just put it in the mean value: `n/2`

If I have:
`vec <- c(0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 8)`

I want to return:
`3 1 8 0 2 4`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example for an uneven vector and also your wxpected output for e.g. `vec <- c(1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. A vector of uneven length might look like: `vec <- c(0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 8, 5)` and desired output would be: `4, 3, 1, 8, 5, 0, 2`. The expected output of your vector would be `2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 1`. Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SOfun` package which has a function called `shifter`:

```
library(SOfun)

shifter(vec, which.max(vec) - length(vec) / 2)
```

**Output**

```
[1] 3 1 8 0 2 4
```

---

In the second case, you have:

```
vec <- c(0, 8, 4, 3, 1, 2)
```

with `max` value before the middle, resulting in a negative shift:

```
shifter(vec, which.max(vec) - length(vec) / 2)
```

**Output**

```
[1] 2 0 8 4 3 1
```

Comment: Hi. This works well for the example provided, but not for every vector. If I have `vec <- c(0, 8, 4, 3, 1, 2)`, I do not get the desired output: `2 0 8 4 3 1`. Thanks.

Comment: @lukehenslee I edited the answer - using `SOfun` package you can use `shifter` function, so that it wouldn't matter if the `max` value is before or after the middle of the vector in terms of position. Does that help?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Works well for vectors with an odd number of terms as well: `vec <- c(0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 8, 5); shifter(vec, which.max(vec) - length(vec) / 2)` gives:
`[1] 4 3 1 8 5 0 2`. Thanks very much.